# How do I find/match a string in Selenium IDE?

Tags: xpath, selenium-ide

I am trying to find a matching string and then click the reply button using Selenium IDE.

I keep getting a 'not found' error.

I tried:

```
/html/body/div[2]/article[2]/div[1]/a[3]/span[contains(text(), 'my-search-string')
```

sample HTML:

```
<article class="thread">
  <div class="threadline normal first"> 
    <span class="area" title="no location given">---</span>  
    <a href="?act=Q&amp;ID=291557485" target="R" class="title">text?</a> &lt;
    <a href="?act=su&amp;handle=my-search-string" target="R" class="handle">
      <span class="handle hnd">my-search-string</span>
    </a> &gt; 
    <button class="BlockButton">Block</button>
    <time>12:14</time>
  </div>     <!-- Added by edit -->
</article>   <!-- Added by edit -->
```

or

```
<div class="threadline normal">  
  <span class="dotz"> : . .  : . .  : . .  : . .  : . . </span> 
  <a href="?act=Q&amp;ID=291557031" target="R" class="title">some text</a> &lt; 
  <a href="?act=su&amp;handle=my-search-string" target="R" class="handle">
    <span class="handle hnd">my-search-string</span>
  </a> &gt; 
  <button class="BlockButton">Block</button>
  <time>12:03</time>   
</div>
```

I get the error:

> 'not found'

How do I use the Selenium IDE to search for the string 'my-search-string' in the expression

```
<span class="handle hnd">my-search-string</span>
```

?

Answer (score 0):

The correct XPath expression is

```
/html/body/div[2]/article[2]/div[1]/a[2]/span[contains(text(), 'my-search-string')]
```

Its output is:

> my-search-string

You were missing a final `]` and your index of the `a` element was off by one.

Comment: that was a paste error. I get the same with that bracket. Its not finding the string. It doesn't appear to be syntax. actual error Failed:
Actual value 'my-search-string' did not match ''

Answer (score 0):

try this selector:

```
//span[text()='my-search-string']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "verifyAttribute":

> Command: verifyAttribute
>
> Target: target@class
>
> Value: value

Example:

> Command: verifyAttribute
>
> Target: /html/body/div[2]/article[2]/div[1]/a[3]@href
>
> Value: ?act=su&handle=my-search-string

OBS: I don't know if this works in the new IDE, i use the old version, 2.9.1.